# Visual studio debugger on Python command in a bash script

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a quite complex bash script on Linux which prepares all the structures and parameters in turn fed to a Python command.
However, I would like to use the Visual Studio debugger on this Python command while running it inside the bash script.

Is this possible? 
How can I start a debug session from the bash script?

P.S.: I've found out a similar issue for C++
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3502#issuecomment-48637124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to have the Python debugger in VS Code execute a Python script because the debugger itself needs to start the Python code to attach to it properly.

You can vote for [this feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1182) to get the functionality you desire.

Comment: Thank you! Hope to get future updates about this soon!